# Regex for given parameters

Tags: regex

I recently had test with regex, but I am not skilled in it.
I try to write something for pattern:

- String must contains 6-16 chars
- String should be start only from char
- String could contain any char, but "-" only once
- String must not end with "-"

I wrote somethin like this `"(^[a-zA-Z]).(/w{6,16}).*(?<!-)$"`, ofcourse it is not correct and not full.

I am very interesting in correct answear with explanaition, you could downvote my question if you think, it shoud be.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yaaaap seems correct. I will try to learn more about regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.{5,15}$)[^-]*(?:-[^-]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tws8uD/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `(?=.{5,15}$)` - a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) requiring 5 to 15 chars up to the string end from the current position
- `[^-]*` - (a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)) 0+ chars other than `-`
- `(?:-[^-]+)?` - an optional [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches 1 or 0 repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^-]+` - 1+ chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string